Sitecore 9.3 personalization is not working on local machine
Sitecore 9.3 personalization is not working on my local machine, but it works in higher environments. I have enabled Xdb.Tracking.Enabled and <add key="exmEnabled:define" value="yes" />.
My xconnect portal is working properly. I have even created custom rules, but they are not triggering during debugging. Is there something I'm missing?



Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Don't use images for stack traces, use the actual text to help SEO for the site please.
